# How long does a Java thread own a CPU time slice?

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system

Each Java thread is mapped to a kernel thread in Windows and in Windows the time slice for thread switching is 10-100ms.

However, from the result of the following simple codes, it seems each thread switches the CPU resource every line of code. Why?

```
class MyThread extends Thread{
    public MyThread(String name){
        super(name);
    }
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
              System.out.println( this.getName()+":"+i);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Thread p = new MyThread("t1");
        p.start();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                System.out.println(    "main:"+i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected and actual output? Also note: the most time consuming activity in your code are the print statements. Which go to the same out, which has all kinds of weird effects....

Comment: I'm curious how you know its switching the CPU based on your example?

Comment: `System.out` is a **buffered** `PrintStream`. The order of execution is not necessarily what you see on the console. But yes, each Java thread has a native thread scheduled by the operating system.

Comment: Given multiple CPUs should not a single thread get full time on same CPU?

Comment: No @prayagupd ... apart from Java processes/threads, OS will usually have lot of other processes to schedule.

Comment: I neglect that I/O resource is involved here. Everything is reasonable after considering the I/O resource besides CPU.

Comment: Re, "...thread switches the CPU resource every line of code..." There aren't very many lines of code in your example, and the important ones result in system calls that perform _blocking I/O_. You might want to study up on what "blocking" means in that context.

Comment: They (the `println` calls) *may* result in syscalls that perform blocking I/O.  But that depends on how much  is output.  While `System.err` autoflushes for `println`, `System.out` does not.  In this case, there is a good chance that much of the output is only written as the application is exiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out.println` is a blocking operation that takes a lot of time compared to everything else you're doing.  It's also synchronized so that only one thread can print a line at a time.

This causes the alternating behaviour you're seeing.  While one thread is printing, the other one has plenty of time to get ready to print, call `println`, and wait for the first thread to complete.  When the first thread finishes printing, the second one gets to print, and the first one will be back waiting for it to finish before it's done.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, you don't tell us what output you are seeing and what you are expecting to see.  So it is not possible to explain the former, or why the latter may be off-base.

However, there are a number of factors that could explain why the output is different to what you expect.

- The output is likely to depend on the number of cores (or hyperthreads) on your system.  And the number of them that the OS makes available to your Java application.
- If there are higher priority threads running in the Java application itself or in other parts of the system, that will perturb time slicing.  (A low priority thread's time-slice *may* be cut short if a high priority thread needs to be scheduled.)
- Java thread rescheduling doesn't just occur due to time slicing.  It can also happen when a thread does blocking I/O, or when it attempts to acquire a `Lock` or a mutex, or `wait(...)` or `sleep(...)` or something similar.
- `System.out.println` has some hidden synchronization going on behind the scenes so that two threads printing at the same time don't cause corruption of the shared buffer data structures.

In short, whatever output you see from that program, it will not be *clear* evidence of time slicing behavior.  (And my guess is that it is not evidence of any significance at all.)

---

But the answer to your question:

> How long does a Java thread own a CPU time slice?

is that it is not possible to predict, and would be very difficult to measure.

Comment: Re, "...not possible to predict." Might be more accurate to say, "not defined." There's nothing in the Java Language Specification that constrains thread scheduling to use time slices of any particular duration.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - Both your statement and my statement are 100% accurate.  But I think mine is more apropos to the question asked.